# Why is the math of my stacking game not working?

Tags: python, math, pygame, collision-detection

This is my first pygame project, and it's a stacking game. I made the game with the idea of any piece not touching the base is chopped off, and it goes on until your piece gets too small or if you reach the top of the screen. The problem with my game here, is that it works if you only stack pieces to the right. However, it falls apart if you start stacking to the left. I checked the math many times already, but it doesn't work still. It calculates the part that is chopped off by taking the base x position of the piece on the bottom, and then subtracting or adding the x position of the piece on top.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
win=pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Stacking Game")
length=200 #The length of you CURRENT piece, the one that is moving
base=0 #X pos of the PREVIOUS stacked piece
x=0 #X pos of current piece
y=750 #y pos of current piece
blocks=0 #How many blocks have been stacked
difference=0
speed=5
direction=1
running=1
lengthbase=0 #Length of the PREVIOUS stacked piece
while (running==1):
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    if direction==1: 
        if x>800-length:
            direction=0
        else:
            x+=speed
    else:
        if direction==0:
            if x<0:
                direction=1
            else:
                x-=speed
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0),(0,0,800,y+50)) #Blacks out the screen from the current piece to the top, leaving previously stacked pieces
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,length,50))
    if blocks==16: #16 is the maximum number of blocks on the screen
        pygame.quit()
        print("You win!")
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
        if blocks==0: #Since the math is all based off the previous piece's length and position, this inserts the information of the first piece. We now know the position and length of the first stacked piece
            base=x
            lengthbase=200
        else:
            if x>base and x<(base+lengthbase): #The current piece should always be the same size and the previous piece, so it can either be stacked perfectly, to the right, or to the left. This calulates data when it is stacked to the right.
                difference=(x+length)-(base+lengthbase)
                length=length-difference
                pygame.draw.rect(win,(0),(0,0,800,y+50))
                pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,length,50)) #Draws the new piece at the same position as the current piece, but with the new length
            else:
                if (x+length)>base and (x+length)<(base+lengthbase): #Calculates if the piece is stacked to the left.
                    difference=base-x
                    length=length-difference
                    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0),(0,0,800,y+50))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x+difference,y,length,50)) #If it was drawn on x, the stacked piece and the one below it would not be aligned. It has to move a distance of difference
                else:
                    pygame.quit()
                    print("You lost.")
        base=x #The stacked piece then becomes the bases for the next piece
        lengthbase=length
        speed+=1 
        blocks+=1
        y-=50
        time.sleep(0.5)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I think a better explanation of the game's intended behavior would be helpful.   Running it didn't seem to help ... it appears that the space bar is meant to trigger an event but that doesn't work for me.  I think you may have an indentation problem, and all the code is meant to be inside the event handling loop?

Comment: for me code was running great it chopped the red thingy on both sides edit: changed my mind code is working not as good as it seemed at first

Answer (score 3):

You have to evaluate if the ranges [x1, x1+w1] and [x2, x2+w2] are overlapping.

Not overlapping:

```
x1      x1+w1
  +----+
            +----+
          x2      x2+w2
```

```
           x1      x1+w1
             +----+
  +----+
x2      x2+w2
```

Overlapping

```
x1                x1+w1
  +--------------+
       +----+
     x2      x2+w2
```

```
     x1      x1+w1
       +----+
  +---------------+
x2                 x2+w2
```

```
x1           x1+w1
  +---------+
       +----------+
     x2            x2+w2
```

```
     x1            x1+w1
       +----------+
  +----------+
x2            x2+w2
```

This mean, that the ranges are overlapping if

```
x1 < x2+w2 and x2 < x1+w1
```

---

You don't need 2 separate cases for left and right. Just evaluate whether the areas overlap. Calculate the beginning and the end of the common area with `min` and `max`:

```py
if x < base + lengthbase and base < x + length:
    start = max(x, base)
    end = min(x+length, base+lengthbase)
    x = start
    length = end - start 
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0),(0,0,800,y+50))
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,length,50))
else:
    pygame.quit()
    print("You lost.")
```

This can be further simplified:

```py
start = max(x, base)
end = min(x+length, base+lengthbase)
if start < end:  
    x, length = start, end - start
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0),(0,0,800,y+50))
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,length,50))
else:
    # [...]
```

---

Side note: You've to handle the events in the event loop, rather than after the event loop:

```py
while running==1:
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
            if blocks==0:
                base=x
                lengthbase=200
            else:
                start = max(x, base)
                end = min(x+length, base+lengthbase)
                if start < end:  
                    x, length = start, end - start
                    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0),(0,0,800,y+50))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,length,50))
                else:
                    pygame.quit()
                    print("You lost.")
            base, lengthbase = x, length 
            speed += 1 
            blocks += 1
            y -= 50
            time.sleep(0.5)
```